# How to input source and target database parameters in IBM Data Replication 11.4.0.4?

Tags: cdc, ibm-data-replication

Though IBM states it supports Oracle, there is no clear cut documentation on how to provide the input parameters like the TNS names inside either the IIDR configuration tool or the Management Console.

[IIDR Configuration not allowing Oracle Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A62c9.png)
[Management Console not allowing Oracle either](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbhjT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot linked refers to the configuration parameters of the IBM CDC agent for Db2, not for Oracle Database.

Current CDC version (11.4+) has a unified installer for all agent types on the particular operating system, however, each source and target type needs to be installed separately. The type of the agent to be installed is asked by the installer.

IBM CDC documentation lists the necessary configuration steps for Oracle: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/idr/11.4.0?topic=databases-configuring-cdc-replication-engine-oracle

Please note the "CDC for XStream" agent configuration as well, for newer Oracle Database versions using some features like long object names and encryption: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/idr/11.4.0?topic=xstream-configuring-cdc-replication-engine-oracle

There are also videos with step-by-step configuration, for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K6veQyQMz94